# @font-face working (locally and in remote server) on Chrome, Safari, Opera but not with Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have my fonts in `my-theme/assets/fonts/my-font.ttf` and this is my .css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Jubilat';
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Jubilat/Jubilat-Light.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Jubilat/Jubilat-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../assets/fonts/Jubilat/Jubilat-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('../assets/fonts/Jubilat/Jubilat-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Jubilat-Light", Helvetica Neue, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This is a Wordpress site. Also, in Firebug I don't see errors. It is working (locally and in remote server) on Chrome, Safari, Opera but **not with Firefox** I really don't know what else to do. Thanks.

[This is the url](http://fltrialcounsel.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have wrong names for font-family http://joxi.ru/krDlgpJsEGz6nr

Comment: Check font urls one more time.

Comment: Yep, it was the names. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've named the font family "Jubilat", so that's what you need to refer to it as, despite the font filenames. So, this should do it...

```
body {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Jubilat", Helvetica Neue, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Alternatively, update the font-face definition and leave the body rule as it is ...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Jubilat-Light';
  ...
```